# Why these String comparison have different results in java?

Tags: java, spring-boot

This throws IllegalStateException, the checkArgument method is Google's `com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument`:

`checkArgument(apikey.equals("3243442-bb73-123-421f-sfsglk"), "Wrong api key.");`

vs.

This gets into the if block:

```
if (apikey.equals("3243442-bb73-123-421f-sfsglk")) {
    // do something
}
```

The apikey value is stored in the Spring boot config file and is retrieved by `@Value("${apikey}")`.

I know this is not how API keys are done, but I needed something quick for a small side project to test something.

Comment: `apikey` must contain something other than you think. You need to debug that.

Comment: I debugged that for a while with different strings and they show in the debugger as the same strings..that's strange

Answer (score 1):

`Spring-Boot` does not trim off the trailing whitespaces in the config files.

If you are sure the key is correct in the config file, this should pass the check:

```
checkArgument(apikey.trim().equals("3243442-bb73-123-421f-sfsglk"), "Wrong api key.");
```